# Can I have customized versions of boostrap 3 in the same site?

Tags: css, zend-framework2, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I downloaded a customized version of bootstrap 3 from the web (I changed the number of columns to 7), but my website uses zf2 which comes packaged with bootstrap 3. How can I have a page of my website use this customized version and have the rest of the site use the standard build?

Will I have to do something with LESS? I'm just unsure of how this would work or if it can work at all.

I tagged this with zf2 because that is my specific use case, but this is more a general boostrap, css question.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Zend-framework, but I would assume it uses some type of templating. Why not customize bootstrap using LESS for your _special_ needs and have a specialized layout that you inherit. Then have a _regular_ layout with a standard version of bootstrap. Is it just the grid that you're customizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want ONE page to use it, why not just output the customized Bootstrap CSS files on that one page, and the standard CSS files on everything else?

Answer (score 0):

No, since both versions of bootstrap use the same class names, you can not use multiple instances of bootstrap on the same page.